# AfterEffects 3d - can I get an outline around an extrusion?

Tags: 3d, animation, adobe-after-effects

Ok, so Ive imported a path from illustrator into AE and made it 3d, so I have this -

[image]

What I want is an outlined version, but of the extruded path. This is rough, but like this:

[image]

Dynamic while it is spinning. Is this possible without significant hacking in AE? Or better to use a 3d program?

Comment: I'd say bring in a proper 3D asset for greatest flexibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly you imported a 2D shape from Illustrator that just looks like a 3D shape. Right now it's as good as a bitmap for what you want; you can't extrude it or rotate it since it's essentially a flat image in a fixed 2D projection.

If you want that to spin (like a cog spinning on its own axis) you need a front view of the cog, extruded in a 3D program then imported to AE. Or you can use [Cinema 4D Lite](https://helpx.adobe.com/after-effects/using/c4d.html) (that is included with AE CC) to create your object. Here's [a video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q7UFDzbQa1s), essentially you'll use the **Pen tool** > **Cogwheel** then **Extrude** it. From there you can delete the front face and tweak the material to get the proper shading.

Answer (score 1):

The extrusion that After Effects creates via the *Geometry Options* settings, doesn't really have a wireframe geometry that could be rendered in the way you need it. You will need to create the extruded element in a 3D software and then import it, as [Luciano](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/130538/52520) already proposed, and continue with that.